# Laravel JSON Where Clauses with number in key

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

I have table with json column "options".
Exemple:

```
 {"language":"en" }
```

When i doing query, it's OK:

```
DB::table('users')->where('options->language', 'en')->get();
```

But if i have number key:

```
{"221":"en" }
```

I get empty array:

```
DB::table('users')->where('options->221', 'en')->get();
```

How i can get true query?
Laravel 5.2

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `whereJsonContains` method. In your case:

```php
DB::table('users')->whereJsonContaints('options', ['221' => 'en'])->get();
```

Comment: whereJsonContains  only laravel >5.6

Comment: For me `->where('options->211', 'en')` is working fine

Answer (score 1):

If you upgrade your version of Laravel to 5.6 or newer the `->whereJsonContains()` will be available.

If you do not want that, you can do it with a `whereRaw` query. The exact implementation depends on what DBMS you have:

#### SQL Server 2016

```
->whereRaw("JSON_VALUE(options, '$.221') = ?", ['en'])
```

#### MySQL

```
->whereRaw("JSON_CONTAINS(options, 'en', '$.221') = 1")
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in later versions of Laravel.

In Laravel 5.2, you can use a raw expression:

```
DB::table('users')->whereRaw('`options`->\'$."221"\' = ?', ['en'])->get();
```